# Adding View Based on Condition is Moving the Existing Elements Upwards in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isOn: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: {
                Text("ON")
            })
            
            if isOn {
                Text("Light is on!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I toggle isOn to true, a Text view is added. When the Text view is added the Toggle pushes upwards. Is there anyway to prevent that? I want to use VStack and not ZStack.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the VStack is centred vertically on the display. When you add more content, its middle changes.

To fix, you could push the content to the top or to the bottom using a `Spacer`. Then add padding if needed. For example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isOn: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: {
                Text("ON")
            })
            .padding(.top, 200) // <- ADDED

            if isOn {
                Text("Light is on!")
            }
            Spacer() // <- ADDED
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can also evaluate using the opacity modifier and the Toggle view will not move at all.

```
struct Stackoverflow01: View {

@State private var isOn: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Toggle(isOn: $isOn, label: {
            Text("ON")
        })
        
        Text("Light is on!")
            .opacity(isOn ? 1 : 0)
    }
}
```

}